# VirtualBox multiple VMs bridged to one NIC

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to run some VMs on my computer, and let those behave like physical computers to the network. I want my normal DHCP to give them IPs, and I want to be able to access them as if they were physical computers.

The host is a powerful desktop computer (not a server) with one network card. I can use bridged networking to have one VM work the way I want, but the second one cannot get an IP. The VMs are using different MAC addresses.

The host is running Windows 7 and the hosts I'm testing with are running Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a reboot solves yet another problem. Rebooted the host machine twice, and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Is there another solution besides rebooting? It's not really an option on shared infrastructure.

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The router you are using has any limitation on the DHCP IPs? What was the error you are getting in the guest? Are they getting any IP address or not? I have done this in Ubuntu (as host), it worked well for me.. I managed to run 4 or 5 VMs with bridged adapter. Not sure any issue with Windows.

Comment: It stops for a while at "waiting for ip" during boot, until it fails and continues.

Comment: Ok. You can try 2 things to debug.
1. Untick the "Enable Network Adapter" and boot. Once you boot run tcpdump inside ubuntu and tick the  "Enable Network Adapter" and see what's going on. May be we can get a clue.
2. Try different type of adapters in the "Advanced" in the Networking tab of VirtualBox. I generally use "Intel PRO/1000MT Desktop". Once I changed that and didn't get the network. Not sure about the error.

Comment: the "waiting for ip" is ubuntu waiting for a dhcp response, which it never gets

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. What about trying different Adapters and see if it helps? Also try NAT/Hostonly and see if it works. So that we can narrow down the issue further. What version of VirtualBox are you trying? May be it is a bug with old VirtualBox.